# Crear un menú interactivo con opciones desplegables alrededor de una imagen

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

Quiero realizar un menú interactivo, al centro la imagen *Cloud* y al pasar el mouse sobre la imagen que me muestre *6 menús* alrededor.

Muestro cómo se vería, el problema es cómo ubicar correctamente los `div` de los menús.

Encontré y apliqué a mi diseño el siguiente código, pero no logro hacer que se mantenga siempre la imagen al centro y los elementos rodeando. Cada vez que redimensiono el navegador se mueven de lugar los elementos:

```css
.container > * {
  position: absolute;
  top: 200px;
  left: 50%;
  width: 70px;
  height: 70px;
  border-radius: 50% !important;
  padding-top: 20px !important;
  font-size: 16px !important;
}

.padre{
width:20%;
height: 20%;
left: 43%;
top: 40%;

/*padding:40px !important;font-size:30px !important;*/
}
.container > :nth-of-type(1) {
  transform: rotate(0deg) translate(10em) rotate(0deg);
}
.container > :nth-of-type(2) {
  transform: rotate(60deg) translate(10em) rotate(-60deg);
}
.container > :nth-of-type(3) {
  transform: rotate(120deg) translate(10em) rotate(-120deg);
}
.container > :nth-of-type(4) {
  transform: rotate(180deg) translate(10em) rotate(-180deg);
}
.container > :nth-of-type(5) {
  transform: rotate(240deg) translate(10em) rotate(-240deg);
}
.container > :nth-of-type(6) {
  transform: rotate(300deg) translate(10em) rotate(-300deg);
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
    <div class="btn btn-success">
        <b>D</b>
    </div>
    <div class="btn btn-success">
        <b>D</b>
    </div>
    <div class="btn btn-success">
        <b>D</b>
    </div>
    <div class="btn btn-success">
        <b>D</b>
    </div>
    <div class="btn btn-success">
        <b>D</b>
    </div>
    <div class="btn btn-success">
        <b>D</b>
    </div>

    <div class="padre">
        <img src="~/Content/svg/cloud/cloud_empresarial.svg" />
    </div>
</div>
```

Mmuestra de ejemplo del menú:

[image: Muestra de ejemplo del menú]

Comment: Saludos y bienvenido te comento que tu pregunta tiene problemas de formato y por ende es casi seguro termine cerrada, considera leer [ask], editar y mostrar lo que lleves al momento

Comment: espero haber podido entender bien las reglas, y muchas gracias por el comentario.

Comment: El problema persiste amigo, ya que no muestras avance alguno y en cambio pides que alguien lo haga y/o que te recomienden librerías motivos para cierre; consejo trata algo por tu cuenta y cuando tengas errores claros entonces eres mas que bienvenido para venir a preguntar

Comment: Bienvenido al sitio, te sugerimos revisar las preguntas que obtienen respuesta en el sitio. Tu pregunta necesita ser más específica,
Edita la pregunta para limitarla a un problema específico, con el suficiente nivel de detalle para permitir identificar una respuesta adecuada.

Comment: gracias, he modificado nuevamente la pregunta, espero ser mas especifico. gracias

Comment: Todos los elementos tienen posición absoluta y todos tienen atributos top en pixeles, excepto la imagen, por eso es que se mueve al redimensionar la ventana.

Answer (score 1):

Quizás buscas algo como esto:

```html
<html>
  <head>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/uikit/dist/css/uikit.min.css">
  </head>
  <body>
<div class="uk-container">
  <div>
    <div class="uk-inline uk-dark">
      <img src="https://getuikit.com/docs/images/light.jpg" alt="">
      <a class="uk-position-absolute uk-transform-center" style="left: 20%; top: 30%" href="javascript: void 0" uk-marker uk-tooltip="Hola mundo #1"></a>
      <a class="uk-position-absolute uk-transform-center" style="left: 60%; top: 40%" href="javascript: void 0" uk-marker uk-tooltip="Hola mundo #2"></a>
      <a class="uk-position-absolute uk-transform-center" style="left: 80%; top: 70%" href="javascript: void 0" uk-marker uk-tooltip="Hola mundo #3"></a>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/uikit"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Si te fijas, cada etiqueta `a` tiene un atributo `style`, el cual sirve para especificar la posición de cada punto marcado en la imagen.